# refactoring Rails 4 before_action for code speed with reused controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, refactoring

I’ve been learning Rails for a while now and I’d like to know what the best way to include reusable methods in other methods is.  I use before_action for some, but I’m wondering if I should convert my code which looks like ‘Fig.A’ to utilize more before actions (Fig. B).  Is this the best practice & does it improve speed?

**Fig.A** 
SomeController.rb

```
def some_action
  #logic
end

def my_method
 some_action
  #logic
end

def my_other_method
 some_action
  #logic
 end
```

versus using a before action

**Fig.B**
SomeController.rb

```
before_action  :some_action, only: [:my_method, :my_other_method]

def some_action
  #logic
end

def my_method
  #logic
end

def my_other_method
  #logic
end
```

I am asking as I am trying to get a handle on best practices and clean code.  Which is the preferred way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked two different questions here. A good way to abstract methods so they are resuable would be in the form of a Module or a superclass which your subclass inherits behavior from. Think of a rails model inheriting ActiveRecord::Base and how it inherits database access methods etc.

You are probably saying that you defined your before action methods in application_controller which is fine, but limiting them for use in certain controllers won't necessarily improve performance. If they are heavy and you only want them to be instantiate on certain controllers, modules would be a better way to go, but they would have to be sufficiently large and complex to gain performance in controllers that to not include them.

Comment: It's actually just one controller with the heavy reused methods and right now I'm just listing the method inside another method (Fig.A)...I just wondered if I should use a before_action instead.  Thanks

Comment: so you like methods in your methods? jk..it's fine. You have nothing to worry about in terms of performance yet. it's hard to give you more information with the limited information in your question

Comment: I don't KNOW if I like methods in methods...my instincts tell me its inefficient and ugly...but before I went and refactored it, I wanted to check. I'm teaching myself, so I'm missing some basic best practices.